Azure APIM can't see http endpoint worrkflow inside standard logic app
I'm trying to expose the API endpoint using APIM. For the backend, I'm trying to use the Logic app's standard workflows. But none of the wf inside the standard logic app is visible.
However, I can see all standalone logic apps (in the consumption plan).
Can anyone suggest to me how to fix this issue?
Thanks,
Deepak Shaw

Do you have a VNET configured in LogicApps?

As per the MS Doc, you can directly import a Consumption logic app to Azure API management which should have When a HTTP request is received trigger in it but the same functionality is not yet available for Standard logic app.

API Management supports automated import of a Logic App (Consumption) resource. which runs in the multi-tenant Logic Apps environment.

In order to import the http endpoints from Standard logic app, you can either refer to this blog or follow the steps given below.

Initially break the callback or workflow URL into 2 parts.
1st Part - https://{LogicAppName}.azurewebsites.net:443/api/
2nd Part - demo/triggers/When_a_HTTP_request_is_received/invoke?api-version=2022-05-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2FWhen_a_HTTP_request_is_received%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=Vs---0o0

Add the 1st part of the URL as Web Service URL in APIM as shown below.



Once done, you can see that the logic app URL is set as backend URL.


Add an operation and then add the 2nd part of the URL as given below.



Now, you can invoke the logic app.


